# Unlock i3lock on i3wm using finger print sensor (fprint)

Tags: arch-linux, authentication, i3, screen-lock, fingerprint

I am trying to set up my i3lock that I would be able to unlock it using finger print sensor on my thinkpad x390 yoga.

I have set up my i3lock in `.config/i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id xss-lock --transfer-sleep-lock -- i3lock -e --indicator --pass-media-keys --pass-screen-keys
```

when I run `sudo fprintd-verify` I can use finger print without any problem:

```
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Listing enrolled fingers:
 - #0: right-index-finger
Verify started!
Verifying: right-index-finger
Verify result: verify-match (done)
```

this is my `/etc/pam.d/i3lock`:

```
# PAM configuration file for the i3lock-color screen locker. By default, it includes
# the 'system-auth' configuration file (see /etc/pam.d/system-auth) for Arch and Gentoo
# and 'system-auth' for Debian. Note that vanilla i3lock upstream uses 'login' instead.

auth sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth include system-auth # For Arch/Gentoo
auth include system-auth # For Debian
```

But still I am not able to unlock i3lock with fingerprint sensor and have to type my password. How can I make it work ?

Thank you for help

---

**Edit:** Looks like it is imposible to achieve this in current version of i3lock. There is [github issue](https://github.com/i3/i3lock/issues/210). The i3lock wants password to be typed before looking to `pam.d` file.